# Show 0 for cumulative count when no data exist for the month

Tags: sql-server

I have a sql table containing site, month, projected count and actual count. The Projected Count is stored as a
cumulative value from my client. The actual count is a derived value from another table.

Below is the screenshot of the table data.

[image]

I want to find the cumulative count for the Actual Cnt data for each month and sitewise. I have done this based on the
below query and its working fine.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
[SiteID] ,
ActualCount ,
CONVERT(DATETIME, [Month], 106) AS [Month] ,
EventName ,
EventValue
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT
[SiteID] ,
ActualCount ,
[Month] ,
CASE WHEN [ActualCount] IS NULL
THEN ISNULL(SUM([ActualCount]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [SiteID]
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, [Month], 106) ),
0)
ELSE ISNULL(SUM([ActualCount]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [SiteID]
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, [Month], 106) ),
0)
END AS CumActSum ,
ISNULL(SUM([ProjectedCount]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [Month],
[SiteID] ORDER BY [Month]
),
0) AS CumProSum
FROM [db_Temp].[dbo].[tbl_site_projection]
) AS src UNPIVOT ( EventValue FOR EventName IN ( CumActSum, CumProSum ) ) AS
UPV
```

Output of the above code is

[image]

The problem is the requirement from my customer. If you look at the data there is no actual count for the month of
december for all the siteid's and is NULL

As per my customer requirement, if there is no Actual Count for all the siteid's for a month, then the cumulative count
for that month must be zero. We must not show the cumulative count for that month.

I tried modifying the code by considering the condition like WHEN ActualCount IS NULL THEN 0. But this removes
the cumulative count from the November Month also.

Basically what they want is whenever the Actual Count is null for all the sites, the cumulative count must not show for
that month and we have to show 0.

Below is the expected output i am looking for.

[image]

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d74b)

There was some problem in the sql fiddle hence i have just built the schema in that.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your case statement to check whether the cumulative sum of actual count is null for the month and if its null or 0 then have it as 0.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        [SiteID] ,
        ActualCount ,
        CONVERT(DATETIME, [Month], 106) AS [Month] ,
        EventName ,
        EventValue
FROM    ( SELECT DISTINCT
                    [SiteID] ,
                    ActualCount ,
                    [Month] ,
                    CASE WHEN SUM([ActualCount]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [Month]) IS NULL
                         THEN 0
                         ELSE ISNULL(SUM([ActualCount]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [SiteID] ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, [Month], 106) ),
                                     0)
                    END AS CumActSum ,
                    ISNULL(SUM([ProjectedCount]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [Month],
                                                        [SiteID] ORDER BY [Month] ),
                           0) AS CumProSum 
          FROM      [db_Temp].[dbo].[tbl_site_projection] GROUP BY [SiteID] ,
                    ActualCount ,
                    [Month], [ProjectedCount] 
        ) AS src UNPIVOT ( EventValue FOR EventName IN ( CumActSum, CumProSum ) ) AS UPV
        WHERE TrialMonth LIKE 'Dec%' AND EventName = 'CumActSum'
        ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, [Month], 106), SiteID
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you handle null directly then?

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    [SiteID] ,
    ISNULL(ActualCount ,0),  --Here I handle NULL
    CONVERT(DATETIME, [Month], 106) AS [Month] ,
    EventName ,
    EventValue
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT
    [SiteID] ,
    ActualCount ,
    [Month] ,
    CASE WHEN [ActualCount] IS NULL
    THEN ISNULL(SUM([ActualCount]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [SiteID]
    ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, [Month], 106) ),
    0)
    ELSE ISNULL(SUM([ActualCount]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [SiteID]
    ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, [Month], 106) ),
    0)
    END AS CumActSum ,
    ISNULL(SUM([ProjectedCount]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [Month],
    [SiteID] ORDER BY [Month]
    ),
    0) AS CumProSum
    FROM [db_Temp].[dbo].[tbl_site_projection]
    ) AS src UNPIVOT ( EventValue FOR EventName IN ( CumActSum, CumProSum ) ) AS
    UPV
```

Other wise make modification in Inner query itself like below and i think there is no need of case condition. You are handling null after the sum. Try null handling before sum. It could avoid some serious issues too.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    [SiteID] ,
    ActualCount 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, [Month], 106) AS [Month] ,
    EventName ,
    EventValue
    FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT
    [SiteID] ,
    ActualCount ,
    [Month] ,
    CASE WHEN [ActualCount] IS NULL
    THEN SUM(ISNULL([ActualCount],0)) OVER ( PARTITION BY [SiteID] --change will be here
    ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, [Month], 106) ),
    0)
    ELSE SUM(ISNULL([ActualCount],0)) OVER ( PARTITION BY [SiteID] --change will be here
    ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, [Month], 106) ),
    0)
    END AS CumActSum ,
    ISNULL(SUM([ProjectedCount]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [Month],
    [SiteID] ORDER BY [Month]
    ),
    0) AS CumProSum
    FROM [db_Temp].[dbo].[tbl_site_projection]
    ) AS src UNPIVOT ( EventValue FOR EventName IN ( CumActSum, CumProSum ) ) AS
    UPV
```